# ruby regexp and enumerable method explained

Tags: ruby, oop

Can someone explain to me what this line of code is doing?

```rb
def count_sentences
  new_array = self.split(/[.?!]/).reject { |string| string.empty? }
  new_array.length
end
```

Answer (score 4):

So that's a patch to the `String` class.  It's meant to allow you to count sentences in a string.

```
'That is a cat.  This is a dog'.count_sentences
>= 2
```

How does it work?

```
def count_sentences  
  new_array = self.split(/[.?!]/).reject {|string| string.empty? }
  return new_array.length   
end
```

`self.split(/[.?!]/)` splits `self` (the string the method is called on) into separate strings separating them by periods, question marks, or exclamation marks. So basically, an array of sentences.

`.reject {|string| string.empty? }` drops all the elements in the array that are empty... so that "hello there..." is just one sentence, not four.  It could be more economically written as `.reject(&:empty?)`

Finally, we return the count of strings in the array with `return new_array.length`. As it's the last line in the method, you don't really need to have the explicit "return"... it's enough to just do `new_array.length`